# Is there any point to raise social stats to rank 5?

Tags: persona-5

I've reached rank 4 on all 5 of my social stats which lets me start (and finish, as far as I can tell) any Social Link. Is there a reason to try and raise them to rank 5?

I know that Knowledge affects the results of the exams and that Proficiency allows to craft more items in one go (which I don't really need any more since I've already crafted the Unbreakable Lockpick, and the rest can be handled by the maid). Is there any use in raising Kindness, Charm and Guts to rank 5?

Comment: At the very least, you get [**a trophy**](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/persona-5-ps4-ps3/trophy/173740-True-Talent.html) for maxing your stats.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a usage for increasing Kindness, Charm, and Guts to Rank 5. These social stats will be used to maximize different confidants.

1. [Sojiro](https://www.hardcoregamer.com/2017/04/04/persona-5-confidant-guide-hierophant-sojiro-sakura/) requires max **kindness** at rank 7
2. [Munehisa](https://www.hardcoregamer.com/2017/04/04/persona-5-confidant-guide-hanged-munehisa-iwai/) requires max **guts** at rank 7.5
3. [Makoto](https://www.hardcoregamer.com/2017/04/04/persona-5-confidant-guide-priestess-makoto-niijima/) requires max **charm**  at rank 6
4. [Haru](https://www.hardcoregamer.com/2017/04/04/persona-5-confidant-guide-empress-haru-okumura/) requires max **proficiency** at rank 2
5. [Hifumi](https://www.hardcoregamer.com/2017/04/04/persona-5-confidant-guide-star-hifumi-togo/) requires max **knowledge** at rank 8